# Comparing MD5 of a field results NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, md5

I have a function to calculate which inputs MD5 of the user id and outputs the `id,name`

```
public function verifyUser($enc)
{
    //echo $enc;
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM `users` WHERE MD5(`id`) = '$enc'");
    //$query->bindValue(1,$enc);
    $query->execute();
    $data = $query->fetch();
    //var_dump($query);
    return $data;
}
```

But the above query always results NULL.

eg I have a user with `id=2` and  `MD5(2)` is `c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c`. The query it generates is :

`SELECT id,name FROM`users`WHERE MD5(`id`) = 'c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c'`

But though the user exits , it results null.

Comment: Does your query return an empty result set or do you get NULL for id and name?

Comment: Also, it seems that you have commented the bindValue part and do not send the value for parameter $enc.

Comment: have you tried it evaluate it manually (paste your query on phpMyadmin, etc.). [here is a sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd97f/1) because its working. md5(2)

Comment: Query is working as expected. check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e262d/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query alone is working as expected. check this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e262d/1

however seems to be the following line has some issue. try this corrected one:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE MD5(id) = '$enc'");
```

note: I have removed the wrong quote character present in your code surrounding users and id.

Comment: Yes the query returns a desired o/p. but when I var_dump the query, It outputs like
`SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE MD5(id) = '
    
     c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
    
   '`

Comment: the white space it generate causing the error i think

Comment: seems to be the issue.